# SAP BO XI 3.1 SP5 with DB2 10.5 connection Using Client 10 z/OS

Tags: db2, business-objects

We have created a report using SAP BO 3.1 SP5 for DB2 9.7 using client 9. Now we have upgraded the DB2 from 9.7 to 10.5. So using client 10 z/OS we have connected the SAP BO, but the generated query differs from what we get while connecting with client 9.  Can anyone explain the issue?

Is it not possible to connect DB10.5 with client 10 z/OS? Is it the generated query have difference by this version difference?

Sorry guys, I am a newbie to BO. Maybe this is a silly question, but we have to answer for this.

Thanks in advance.

I have attached the generated query below:

**Generated By Client 9:**

```
    SELECT
  RPT_EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME,
  RPT_EMPLOYEE.MIDDLE_NAME,
  RPT_EMPLOYEE.LAST_NAME,
  GENDER.ITEM_VALUE,
  RPT_EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT,
  SUB_DEPARTMENT.ITEM_VALUE,
  RPT_EMPLOYEE.JOB_TITLE,
  WD_JOB_GROUP.GROUP_NO,
  WD_GLBT_LIST.DESCRIPTION,
  WD_EEO_LIST.DESCRIPTION,
  CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.HAS_DISABILITY = -1 THEN  ' ' ELSE DISABILITY.ITEM_VALUE  END,
  RPT_NEW_HIRE.HIRE_DT,
  PART_OF_TEN.ITEM_VALUE,
  WD_CLUB.LONG_NAME,
  CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_ADDED <> 0 THEN HIRE_SOURCE.ITEM_VALUE ELSE '' END || '' || 
  CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.PROMOTED <> 0 THEN CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_ADDED <> 0 THEN ',' ELSE '' END || PROMOTED.ITEM_VALUE ELSE '' END || '' || 
  CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_DEACTIVATED <> 0 THEN CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_ADDED <> 0 THEN ',' ELSE '' END || DEACTIVATED.ITEM_VALUE || '-' ELSE '' END || '' || 
  CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_DEACTIVATED <> 0 THEN DEACTIVATION_REASON.ITEM_VALUE ELSE ' ' END
FROM
  WD_KEY_LIST  DEACTIVATION_REASON 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RPT_DEACTIVATION ON RPT_DEACTIVATION.REASON_CODE=DEACTIVATION_REASON.ITEM_ID AND DEACTIVATION_REASON.KEY_ID=7 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN RPT_EMPLOYEE ON RPT_DEACTIVATION.SURVEY_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID  AND  RPT_DEACTIVATION.CLUB_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.CLUB_ID  AND  RPT_EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID=RPT_DEACTIVATION.EMP_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RPT_NEW_HIRE ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID=RPT_NEW_HIRE.SURVEY_ID  AND  RPT_EMPLOYEE.CLUB_ID=RPT_NEW_HIRE.CLUB_ID  AND  RPT_EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID=RPT_NEW_HIRE.EMP_ID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_CLUB ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.CLUB_ID=WD_CLUB.CLUB_ID  AND  WD_CLUB.SURVEY_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_GLBT_LIST ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID=WD_GLBT_LIST.SURVEY_ID  AND  WD_GLBT_LIST.GLBT_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.GLBT_ID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_EEO_LIST ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID=WD_EEO_LIST.SURVEY_ID  AND  WD_EEO_LIST.EEO_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.EEO_ID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_JOB_GROUP ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID=WD_JOB_GROUP.SURVEY_ID  AND  WD_JOB_GROUP.JOB_GROUP_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.JOB_GROUP_ID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  GENDER ON GENDER.ITEM_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.GENDER_ID AND GENDER.KEY_ID = 1  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  PART_OF_TEN ON PART_OF_TEN.ITEM_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_TOP_10 AND PART_OF_TEN.KEY_ID=20 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  HIRE_SOURCE ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_ADDED=HIRE_SOURCE.ITEM_ID and HIRE_SOURCE.KEY_ID=12 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  PROMOTED ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.PROMOTED=PROMOTED.ITEM_ID AND PROMOTED.KEY_ID=13 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  DISABILITY ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.HAS_DISABILITY=DISABILITY.ITEM_ID and DISABILITY.KEY_ID=4 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  DEACTIVATED ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_DEACTIVATED=DEACTIVATED.ITEM_ID AND DEACTIVATED.KEY_ID=14 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_SURVEY  SURVEY ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID=SURVEY.SURVEY_ID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  SUB_DEPARTMENT ON SUB_DEPARTMENT.ITEM_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.SUB_DEPARTMENT AND SUB_DEPARTMENT.KEY_ID = 21
WHERE
  (
   SURVEY.SHORT_NAME  IN  ('*******')
   AND
   SUB_DEPARTMENT.ITEM_VALUE  =  '*****'
  )
```

Generated By Client 10 z/OS:

```
    SELECT
  RPT_EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME,
  RPT_EMPLOYEE.MIDDLE_NAME,
  RPT_EMPLOYEE.LAST_NAME,
  GENDER.ITEM_VALUE,
  RPT_EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT,
  SUB_DEPARTMENT.ITEM_VALUE,
  RPT_EMPLOYEE.JOB_TITLE,
  WD_JOB_GROUP.GROUP_NO,
  WD_GLBT_LIST.DESCRIPTION,
  WD_EEO_LIST.DESCRIPTION,
  CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.HAS_DISABILITY = -1 THEN  ' ' ELSE DISABILITY.ITEM_VALUE  END,
  RPT_NEW_HIRE.HIRE_DT,
  PART_OF_TEN.ITEM_VALUE,
  WD_CLUB.LONG_NAME,
  CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_ADDED <> 0 THEN HIRE_SOURCE.ITEM_VALUE ELSE '' END || '' || 
  CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.PROMOTED <> 0 THEN CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_ADDED <> 0 THEN ',' ELSE '' END || PROMOTED.ITEM_VALUE ELSE '' END || '' || 
  CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_DEACTIVATED <> 0 THEN CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_ADDED <> 0 THEN ',' ELSE '' END || DEACTIVATED.ITEM_VALUE || '-' ELSE '' END || '' || 
  CASE WHEN RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_DEACTIVATED <> 0 THEN DEACTIVATION_REASON.ITEM_VALUE ELSE ' ' END
FROM
  WD_KEY_LIST  SUB_DEPARTMENT 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RPT_EMPLOYEE ON SUB_DEPARTMENT.ITEM_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.SUB_DEPARTMENT AND SUB_DEPARTMENT.KEY_ID = 21
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN RPT_NEW_HIRE ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID=RPT_NEW_HIRE.SURVEY_ID  AND  RPT_EMPLOYEE.CLUB_ID=RPT_NEW_HIRE.CLUB_ID  AND  RPT_EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID=RPT_NEW_HIRE.EMP_ID 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN WD_CLUB ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.CLUB_ID=WD_CLUB.CLUB_ID  AND  WD_CLUB.SURVEY_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN WD_GLBT_LIST ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID=WD_GLBT_LIST.SURVEY_ID  AND  WD_GLBT_LIST.GLBT_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.GLBT_ID 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN WD_EEO_LIST ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID=WD_EEO_LIST.SURVEY_ID  AND  WD_EEO_LIST.EEO_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.EEO_ID RIGHT 
  OUTER JOIN WD_JOB_GROUP ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID=WD_JOB_GROUP.SURVEY_ID  AND  WD_JOB_GROUP.JOB_GROUP_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.JOB_GROUP_ID 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  GENDER ON GENDER.ITEM_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.GENDER_ID AND GENDER.KEY_ID = 1  
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  PART_OF_TEN ON PART_OF_TEN.ITEM_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_TOP_10 AND PART_OF_TEN.KEY_ID=20 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  HIRE_SOURCE ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_ADDED=HIRE_SOURCE.ITEM_ID and HIRE_SOURCE.KEY_ID=12 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  PROMOTED ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.PROMOTED=PROMOTED.ITEM_ID AND PROMOTED.KEY_ID=13 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  DISABILITY ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.HAS_DISABILITY=DISABILITY.ITEM_ID and DISABILITY.KEY_ID=4 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN RPT_DEACTIVATION ON RPT_DEACTIVATION.SURVEY_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID  AND  RPT_DEACTIVATION.CLUB_ID=RPT_EMPLOYEE.CLUB_ID  AND  RPT_EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID=RPT_DEACTIVATION.EMP_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  DEACTIVATION_REASON ON RPT_DEACTIVATION.REASON_CODE=DEACTIVATION_REASON.ITEM_ID AND DEACTIVATION_REASON.KEY_ID=7  
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN WD_KEY_LIST  DEACTIVATED ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.IS_DEACTIVATED=DEACTIVATED.ITEM_ID AND DEACTIVATED.KEY_ID=14 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN WD_SURVEY  SURVEY ON RPT_EMPLOYEE.SURVEY_ID=SURVEY.SURVEY_ID
WHERE
  ( SURVEY.CREATED_BY=SURVEY.IS_CREATED  )
  AND  
  (
   SURVEY.SHORT_NAME  IN  ('*******')
   AND
   SUB_DEPARTMENT.ITEM_VALUE  =  '*******'
  )
```

The differences are instead of LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN have added in client 10 z/OS and the additional condition SURVEY.CREATED_BY=SURVEY.IS_CREATED added in client 10 z/OS.

Comment: What is the difference you are describing?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @laylarencee. 
joins and where conditions in the generated query have difference

Comment: Could you edit the question and provide an example or two of these differences?

Comment: Sorry guys, It's a ODBC related issue. Some expert in our organization fix the issue. I do not know exact solution.